# How do i redo commit after Revert?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have used "Revert changes from this revision" and i now want to redo these changes again. The reason that i used "Revert changes from this revision" in the first place was that the code was bad so i need to redo it with few minor changes.

What's the best approach to do this ?

I should mention that i can't use "Revert to this revision" since other changes has been made which i don't want to revert to. I just want to have the changes back from the specific version that i reverted.

/Mihai

Answer (score 0):

You can Export the files from the revision that has the best approach of the file, then overwrite the files from the revision to be changed.

Use the Diff function to review the code and revert block by block the undesired changes.