# How to redo merge after reverting?

Tags: git

I have merged master branch into my branch A last month, but then I reverted it. After that, new changes have been commited. Now I want to merge the master branch again, and I found that I couldn't merge the commits of master before "reverting" of the branch A, i.e.
Master:  commit1--commit2--commit3-----commit4
                                            \                                     \
A:       commit5--commit6-------merge-revert-commit7-merge
Now git has considered my revert as a new commit and don't take changes in commit1 and 2 in branch A. What can I do?

Similar questions are here:
[I reverted a merge in git, now how do I redo the merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402364/i-reverted-a-merge-in-git-now-how-do-i-redo-the-merge)
[How do i redo commit after Revert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853464/how-do-i-redo-commit-after-revert)

Comment: The short answer is revert the revert. Please edit the question to use a code block for that branch representation, it’s not clear what it means atm

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is *rewrite* the branch so that git does *not* consider it as being merged anymore.... and your *branch chart* does *not* make clear what the branches look like.... here's one example I am creating out of thin air:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- I <- J <- (master)
     ^                  /
      \ F <- G <- H <--
                  ^
                   \ K <- (feature)
```

So.... in `J`, we reverted the merge done in `I`.... how can we then try to merge feature knowing that a part of it (or even all of it) was already merged/reverted? That will confuse git, right?

We just rewrite the branch so that git does *not* see the branch as being merged anymore:

```
    git checkout B
    git cherry-pick B..K
    git branch -d feature # set feature over here
```

After this is done, we get this:

```
      / F' <- G' <- H' <- K' <- (feature)
     v
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- I <- J <- (master)
     ^                  /
      \ F <- G <- H <--
```

And git will *not* consider any of the revisions in `B..feature` to be merged, so this should work:

```
    git checkout master
    git merge develop
```

Which should give you:

```
      / F' <- G' <- H' <- K' <-------- (feature)
     v                            \
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- I <- J <- L <- (master)
     ^                  /
      \ F <- G <- H <--
```